# How to store values(i.e. 'Y'- for checked, 'N' - for unchecked) of multiple checkbox in database using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

[I've attached the screenshot of my module. I want the store the values('Y','N') of selected checkbox in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAdyK.png)

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in RoleOperation track by $index">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>
        <label>{{RoleOperation[$index].vname}}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>{{RoleOperation[$index].id}}</label>
    </td>

    <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="data.viewflg[$index]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="data.addflg[$index]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="data.editflg[$index]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="data.deleteflg[$index]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here **RoleOperation** is Object, which contains names of categories.
How to give value to data-ng-model? And how to access particular checkbox in controller?
plz help me..

Comment: You are using ngModel, so that's all you need.

Comment: If any one knows the answer plz let me know... I want to get checked check box's values in controller. what **ng-model** should I give to each checkbox? To differentiate ng-model of each checkbox, I've passed **$index** to model. **Please refer attached screenshot**. Thank YOU.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-true-value and ng-false-value to set your preferred values.

To set Y and N use the below code.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="data.viewflg[$index]" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'">
```

-- EDIT --

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/r6e7ob8x/1/) is a sample

Comment: Pardon me..I'm new to angularjs.How to use these check boxes in controller?